# Outputting string as innerHTML, but won't render as HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string literal that I am populating with data from a React app. The string literal is saved to localStorage and retrieved later on.

String Literal -

```
 const newDOM = `<div>${Name} <br/>
                    ${Address} <br />
                    ${City} ${State} ${Postal}</div>`;
```

When I retrieve it here

```
this.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('Tom-Hanks-Address')
```

It's inserted into the DOM with quotes still, the divs aren't rendered as HTML.

Here is the DOM -

```
<div id="Address" class="address-check">"<div>Tom Hank's <br/>
                    123 Hanks Dr. <br/>
                    Pensacola FL 444444</div>"
</div>
```

Comment: Are you retrieving it from within a React app as well or is this on a separate non-react page?

Comment: If I use `this.innerHTML = "<div>String</div>"` it is now quote-less in the DOM, but it still renders the divs as strings.

Comment: Retrieving in the same app in a child component. @CarlosReyes

Comment: I've used https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser for similar use cases - I wouldn't recommend setting innerHTML as you're skipping `render()` at that point - I would have the HTML string be a part of state (maybe setting a default), then use `Parser(this.state.tomHanksAddress)` within your `render()` method to update the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

when trying to update the innerHTML in React you have to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: '<strong>First Second</strong>'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

demo here
https://jsbin.com/matigijosa/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing string to html, in vanilla JS:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(localStorage.getItem('Tom-Hanks-Address'), 'text/html');
this.innerHTML = htmlDoc.body.innerText;
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser